# TextInputLayout для spinner

Tags: android, material-design, android-xml

Есть некий макет, вот его кусок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На самом деле вопроса два, но один выходит из второго: Каким образом делается надпись над первым `EditText` (конкретно хмл или метод, знаю что через `TextInputLayout` делается).

Второй - как сделать `TextInputLayout` для, например, `spinner`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помещаете `EditText` в `TextInputLayout` и все. Надпись делается сама, указываете атрибут `androi:hint` для него или для `EditText` (можно использовать связанный метод `setHint()` и у того и у другого).
При этом в неактивном виджете надпись будет в поле ввода, когда фокус перейдет к нему, надпись сместится вверх.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="@string/form_username"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[Подробнее](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/textinputlayout.php) о виджете.

Также в качестве вложенного виджета вместо `EditText` можно использовать `TextInputEditText` из библиотеки поддержки *Design*, который фиксит баг с подсказкой при использовании [полноэкранного режима](http://w3bshark.com/blog/input-layouts) ввода

Для спиннера делают [сторонние библиотеки](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31837938).